# In C, unable to get an array to save new values

Tags: c, arrays

So I'm writing a function that is to increment the value of an element in the array and return void. However I'm unable to get the new value to carry back into main. The code is as follows:

```
void incrementInt(int myInt, int increment_val)
{ 
    myInt += increment_val
}
```

The call to the function is incrementInt(myInt[i], value). When I run a printf within the function, it is modifying the values, but a printf back in main has the original values.

Answer (score 5):

In C you pass everything to functions by value, that means the original value doesn't get changed.
You can pass the address of the variable, dereference it and the original value will be changed.

Example:

```
void incrementInt(int * myInt, int increment_val)
{ 
    *myInt += increment_val
}
```